# BroadcastReceiver in Service is not working after boot completed

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am using a Service to listen for a broadcast after boot completed. But the BroadcastReceiver is not registering when boot completed. If instead of a Service I use a BroadcastReceiver to listen for boot completed it works. It doesn't when I register it with a Service. What am I doing wrong? Code is given below.

```
private BroadcastReceiver sim_change;
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(action);

    sim_change = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boradcast Receiver registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(sim_change, filter);

}@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(sim_change);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boradcast Receiver unregistered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: How you are starting service?

Comment: Are u using which Anroid SDK? its 4.0 ?

Comment: from an activity by calling start service

Answer (score 0):

You have to register for `BOOT_COMPLETED` in your Manifest. It doesn't make sense to register for it from a Service, because the Service won't be running at boot in order to register for it.

Comment: yeah i know i tried that but thing is i want to enable the broadcast receiver and later disable it on button click

Comment: @Akhil To disable/reenable the receiver with `PackageManger`, you still register for the broadcast in your manifest and then call `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to change its enabledness. If you're having trouble getting that working, you should post your code that tries to accomplish it as another question. That's completely unrelated to why your code here is failing to receive the broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

You can't register for `BOOT_COMPLETED` from within a `Service` because the reboot removes that registration.

You must do it from your `BroadcastReceiver`.

There are many ways to handle the enable/disable feature - either using the suggested `setComponentEnabledSetting()`, or just by storing a value in the app's shared preferences, which you can check when your service starts.